# How a value is being retrieved with partial function

Tags: javascript, function, composition, function-composition

I have the following codes:

```
const PENDING = 'PENDING';
const FULFILLED = 'FULFILLED';
const REJECTED = 'REJECTED';

class simplePromise {
  
  constructor(callback) {
    this.state = PENDING;
    this.value = null;
    // here so I can execute all the functions
    this.handlers = [];
    this.doResolve(callback, this.resolve.bind(this), this.reject.bind(this));
  }

  doResolve(callback, onResolved, onRejected) {
    let done = false;
    console.log(callback, 'callback')
    callback((val) => {
      console.log(val, 'val')
      if (done) return;
      done = true;
      onResolved(val)
    })
  }

  resolve(val) {
    this.state = FULFILLED;
    this.value = val;
    this.handlers.forEach(handler => handler);
  }

  reject(error) {
    this.state = REJECTED;
    this.value = error;
    this.handlers.forEach(handler => handler);
  }
}


const promiseA = new simplePromise( (resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
  resolutionFunc(777);
});
```

What puzzles me is the following lines:

```
callback((val) => {
      console.log(val, 'val')
```

The value of `val` is correctly `777`. However, I don't understand why. According to my understanding, I originally pass in a callback function with 2 arguments, so I thought `val` would have the value of

```
(resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
  resolutionFunc(777);
}
```

How does it correctly figure out the value in this case to be `777`?

Comment: `callback` is the function you pass to `constructor`. Then you are calling it with `callback((val) => {...})` in `doResolve`, i.e. you are passing a function as first argument to the callback. That function is assigned to `resolutionFunc`, which gets called as `resolutionFunc(777);`.

Comment: Thanks for the TL;DR version @FelixKling ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused. So now `callback` is equal to `resolutionFunc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a real good question... And I it takes nerves to attempt a clear answer. I fear having to edit 400 times to improve that first quick draft. Hopefully, it will remain a draft, but will be enought to jump in some more in-dept tutorials after.

---

First, that really is a ***simplePromise***, since as is, it just cannot be rejected.

You correctly identified what is here called `callback`... That is the function passed to the `simplePromise` instance.

Now notice that in the promise constructor, there is a function call:

```
this.doResolve(callback, this.resolve.bind(this), this.reject.bind(this));
```

where the `callback` is passed as the 1st argument and the other argument respectively are the `resolve` and `reject` functions defined as methods of the class. `doResolve` executes right away at promise instanciation.

So executing `doResolve`, the `callback` is called... Again passing it a function as first argument:

```
(val) => {
  console.log(val, 'val')
  if (done) return;
  done = true;
  onResolved(val)
}
```

That function in fact, is the `resolutionFunc` argument of the `callback` that was provided to the promise!

So fun... So fun...

Stay with me! So we still are at the `callback` execution... And we call `resolutionFunc` with `777` as argument. We could have passed in a `rejectionFunc` function too.

And that is where we finally execute:

```
(val) => {
  console.log(val, 'val')
  if (done) return;
  done = true;
  onResolved(val)
}
```

That's why console logging `val` outputs `777`... It never went anywhere else. It was directly passed from `resolutionFunc(777)`.

So Is it is just a bunch functions passed as a function to call themselves? In short?

Yes... But there is an advantage to it. The advantage of the promise "structure" is to have a whole set of way more complex functions, that would be repetitive otherwize, in a `class` and pass in just the "real use-case" changing part (the `callback`).

It allows to have a repetitive *mecanism* out of the way from the rest of the logic when programming.

There also is an object binded to the instance, notably the `state` which could be used by `.done()`, `.fail()` etc... So some more complex logic can be chained using the object.

What is missing in this too simple promise... Is a *really doing something* aside just returning the provided value untouched. It could be a check if it is a number... Or server response check, if you think about Ajax for example.

---

Below, I just added some console logs with numbers... So you can notice the order of execution. ;)

```js
const PENDING = 'PENDING';
const FULFILLED = 'FULFILLED';
const REJECTED = 'REJECTED';

class simplePromise {
  
  constructor(callback) {
    this.state = PENDING;
    this.value = null;
    // here so I can execute all the functions
    this.handlers = [];
    this.doResolve(callback, this.resolve.bind(this), this.reject.bind(this));
  }

  doResolve(callback, onResolved, onRejected) {
    console.log("1")
    console.log(callback)
    let done = false;
    callback((val) => {
      console.log("2")
      if (done) return;
      done = true;
      onResolved(val)
    })
  }

  resolve(val) {
    console.log("3")
    this.state = FULFILLED;
    this.value = val;
    this.handlers.forEach(handler => handler);
  }

  reject(error) {
    console.log("4")
    this.state = REJECTED;
    this.value = error;
    this.handlers.forEach(handler => handler);
  }
}


const promiseA = new simplePromise( (resolutionFunc, rejectionFunc) => {
  console.log("5")
  console.log(resolutionFunc)
  resolutionFunc(777);
});
```

---

Why `5` is logged before `2`?

Because `console.log("2")` is inside a function statement that is passed as an argument. And that function is called inside `callback` right after `console.log("5")`

`resolutionFunc` is:

```
(val) => {
  console.log("2")
  if (done) return;
  done = true;
  onResolved(val)
}
```

The key is to notice the when a function statement is getting called. I added two console logs to the snippet... hoping to make it obvious.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I have 2 questions: 1) So basically the `callback` is equivalent to `resolutionFunc` and then the argument `777` is passed right in to the `callback` in `doResolve`? 2) How does `5` appear after `1` and before `2`?

Comment: No. `resolutionFunc` is a function passed as an argument to `callback`. I edited.